# Autotool automake output executable filename with version

Tags: c, autotools, automake

I'm trying to add to the output executable filename of a autotool project the version number.

With libs is very simple: you can add `-version-info` option to `Makefile.am`

**How can I do the same thing with `bin_PROGRAMS`**

So far I tried:

```
HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT = 1
HELLO_VERSION_REVISION = 2
HELLO_VERSION_AGE = 1

bin_PROGRAMS = hello_${HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT}_${HELLO_VERSION_REVISION}_${HELLO_VERSION_AGE}
hello_SOURCES = hello.c
```

In this way it doesn't compile because of `SOURCES` must be: `hello_1_2_1_SOURCES`, but I don't know how to tell to automake that.

Another way could be to run a post-build script: how can I add post-build action to `Makefile.am`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using some [preset `autoconf` output variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf#Initializing-configure) in your `Makefile.am`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello_@PACKAGE_VERSION@

hello_@PACKAGE_VERSION@_SOURCES = hello.c
```

The preceding works for me on Darwin with `autoconf` v2.69 and `automake` v1.15.

Using the `PACKAGE_VERSION` from within your source code is even easier: `#include "config.h"`, that's where all the autoconf output variables are `#define`d. E.g.:

```
/* config.h.  Generated from config.h.in by configure. */
/* config.h.in.  Generated from configure.ac by autoheader. */

...

#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.2.3-rc-whatever"
```

Reference:

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf#Output-Variable-Index

Comment: Ok. It works. Thanks. My problem with this solution is: how I can access version string in source code? I tried -D@PACKAGE_VERSION@ but it doesn't work.

Comment: @LPs, see my latest edit about `#include "config.h"`. The `autoconf`-generated `config.h` contains preprocessor definitions for (nearly) all such output variables.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I add the following to my `Makefile.am`

```
all:
    cp ./.libs/hello ./.libs/hello_${HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT}_${HELLO_VERSION_REVISION}_${HELLO_VERSION_AGE}
```

**EDIT**
I found a new solution

```
HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT = 1
HELLO_VERSION_REVISION = 2
HELLO_VERSION_AGE = 1

bin_PROGRAMS = hello_$(HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT)_$(HELLO_VERSION_REVISION)_$(HELLO_VERSION_AGE)
hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__SOURCES = hello.c

hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__CFLAGS =
hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__LDFLAGS =

AM_CFLAGS = @hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__CFLAGS@
AM_LDFLAGS = @hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__LDFLAGS@

CLEANFILES = *~
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you are (un)defining the `hello___`... variables to empty before assigning to the `AM_`... variables the same value. Are you trying to clear the default compiler and linker flags?

Comment: @rubicks It is the default am file generated by autotool that use that sintax. I only modified it with my version defines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT = 1
HELLO_VERSION_REVISION = 2
HELLO_VERSION_AGE = 1

bin_PROGRAMS = hello_$(HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT)_$(HELLO_VERSION_REVISION)_$(HELLO_VERSION_AGE)
hello_$(HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT)_$(HELLO_VERSION_REVISION)_$(HELLO_VERSION_AGE)_SOURCES = hello.c
```

Although, in that case, I'd suggest making shorter variable names...

Comment: This was what I tried as first solution, but it didn't work. Gave me compilation error due to an error on generated Makefile.

Comment: You had `{curly braces}` in your original post; did you try with `(parentheses)`?

Comment: No, I didn't. Good tip. I try and I'll let you know.

Comment: I found the correct way with underscores. `hello___HELLO_VERSION_CURRENT____HELLO_VERSION_REVISION____HELLO_VERSION_AGE__SOURCES`